# Listview to recyclerview: how do I implement 2 possible viewholders?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my `Listview` this code works:

```
    for (int number = 0; number < matchingContacts.size(); number++) {

        //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts
        if (matchingContacts.contains(selectPhoneContact.getPhone()))

        {
            //if a matching contact, no need to show the Invite button
            viewHolder.invite.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //once a matching contact is found, no need to keep looping x number of time, move onto next contact
            break;

        } else {
            //if not a matching contact, no need to show the check box
            viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }
```

If a phone number is in the `matching` arraylist then it should make the `invite button` invisible, if it is not in the `matching` arraylist it should make the `checkbox` invisible.

But not in my `recyclerview`, in which I am trying to make the code work.

On first load it looks ok but as soon as you start to scroll the views get messed up - checkboxes and buttons appear where they are not supposed to.

I've read that in Recyclerview you are supposed to implement this with `case statements`, and I've looked here [Why RecyclerView items disappear with scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230577/why-recyclerview-items-disappear-with-scrolling) and here [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) but for the life of me I cannot get it to work!

Can you help?

Here is my code:

```
public class PopulistoContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopulistoContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //make a List containing info about SelectPhoneContact objects
    public List<SelectPhoneContact> theContactsList;

    Context context_type;

    ArrayList<String> matchingContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //In each recycler_blueprint show the items you want to have appearing
        public TextView title, phone;
        public CheckBox check;
        public Button invite;


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //title is cast to the name id, in recycler_blueprint,
            //phone is cast to the id called no etc
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
            invite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
            check = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

        }

    }

    public PopulistoContactsAdapter(List<SelectPhoneContact> selectPhoneContacts, Context context, int activity) {

        theContactsList = selectPhoneContacts;
        context_type = context;

        matchingContacts.add("+3531234567");
        matchingContacts.add("+3536789012");
        matchingContacts.add("+3530987654");
        matchingContacts.add("+3538765432");

    }

    @Override
    public PopulistoContactsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_blueprint, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PopulistoContactsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //bind the views into the ViewHolder
        //selectPhoneContact is an instance of the SelectPhoneContact class.
        //We will assign each row of the recyclerview to contain details of selectPhoneContact:

        //The number of rows will match the number of contacts in our contacts list
        final SelectPhoneContact selectPhoneContact = theContactsList.get(position);

        //a text view for the name, set it to the matching selectPhoneContact
        TextView title = viewHolder.title;
        title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());

        //a text view for the number, set it to the matching selectPhoneContact
        TextView phone = viewHolder.phone;
        phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());

        Button invite = viewHolder.invite;

        CheckBox check = viewHolder.check;

        for (int number = 0; number < matchingContacts.size(); number++) {

            //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts
            if (matchingContacts.contains(selectPhoneContact.getPhone()))

            {
                //if a matching contact, no need to show the Invite button
                viewHolder.invite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //once a matching contact is found, no need to keep looping x number of time, move onto next contact
                break;

            } else {
                //if not a matching contact, no need to show the check box
                viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return theContactsList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: "how do I implement 2 possible viewholders?" -- you appear to have only one `ViewHolder` class in this code. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/RecyclerView/HeaderList) for an example of using two different `ViewHolder` classes. "In my Listview this code works" -- not if that is the only code. In `getView()` of a `ListAdapter`, you need to update **every*** widget, because rows get recycled. In your case, you are hiding widgets, but never showing them. Your `RecyclerView.Adapter` suffers from this problem.

Comment: I'll have a look at the sample app. I was trying to implement the two viewholders in my recyclerview but was getting so many errors I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView can handle multiple view types with different view holders.

First of all you have to override the `getItemViewType(int position)` method on your adapter which will return type of the object according its position. Then create view holder class for each view type.

Handle `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` method considering the view type:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == YOUR_FIRST_TYPE) {
        //inflate first type of view
        return new FirstTypeViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == YOUR_SECOND_TYPE) {
        //inflate second type of view
        return new SecondTypeViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

Handle `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)` considering the view type:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (viewType == YOUR_FIRST_TYPE) {
        FirstTypeViewHolder firstTypeViewHolder = (FirstTypeViewHolder) viewHolder;
        //do your stuff
    } else if (viewType == YOUR_SECOND_TYPE) {
        SecondTypeViewHolder secondTypeViewHolder = (SecondTypeViewHolder) viewHolder;
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

You can take a look on this [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example).

Comment: Hey Alex, you should probably avoid posting link-only answers as links can be broken in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Actually in you case, using multiple View types is not necessary. This might be an easier way. Instead, I would recommend you amend your `SelectPhoneContact` class to include a simple boolean field (maybe called `isMatching`) that flags whether or not this phone number is a matching contact. You can then create a simple setter and getter methods like `setIsMatchingContact(boolean)` and `isMatchingContact()` to update/read this flag.

When you're initializing the list and adding the `SelectPhoneContact`, do the pre-processing of determining which instances belong or don't belong in the matching contacts by setting the `setIsMatchingContact(boolean)` method. In your `onBindViewHolder` method, rather than iterating over `matchingContacts`, you just check `selectPhoneContact.isMatchingContact()` and change the visibility accordingly. This is also more efficient as you don't have to perform a potentially expensive operation of iterating through a large list in a bind method which could cause the scrolling to stutter and have issues.

If your `matchingContacts` list changes throughout time, you could always write a method that iterates through the `SelectPhoneContact` list and resets the `isMatching` boolean.

**Method 2:** If you rather not extend the your `SelectPhoneContact` class to have those two methods I mentioned, you could alternatively create a private static wrapper class like this:

```
private static class SelectPhoneContactItem {
    SelectPhoneContact selectPhoneContact;
    boolean isMatching;
}
```

Then use this as the primary list in your adapter:

```
public List<SelectPhoneContactItem> theContactsList;
```

Like Method 1, you should the pre-processing of the figuring out which `SelectPhoneContactItem` is in the `matchingContacts` and assign the `isMatching` boolean as needed.

You should probably go with Method 1 unless there are some design constraints. Let me know if my answer makes sense, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For method 1, getters and setters, do you mean     `boolean isMatching;

    public boolean isMatching(){return isMatching;}
    public void setIsMatchingContact(boolean isMatching){
        this.isMatching = isMatching;

    }`?That kind of thing? I'm useless with them. For method 2, preprocessing and figuring out, sure am I not going to have to use `for,if,else`, which will have to iterate through anyway?

Comment: Your answer to Method 1 is correct. Method 2 really is the same thing as Method 1, it's just a small suggestion if you don't want to modify your `SelectPhoneContact` class (either because it's some external library class you can't modify or want to extend, or if you just want to keep your class code clean from view/controller logic). I shouldn't have really call them Method 1 and 2, sorry for the confusion. They're functionally the same approach.