# Recyclerview hides/shows items on scroll

Tags: android

Thank you for reading. I have this recyclerview that gets passed a 1000 item list in the adapter. And on scroll some of my items disappear and reappear. What do you think the problem is??

Comment: bcoz recylerview recreate items whenever you scroll it takes time to hide previous info in items & modify new info. It happen may be usage of complex item layouts and more methods working in main thread to load recylerview data.

Comment: Please view this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230577/why-recyclerview-items-disappear-with-scrolling

Comment: Thank you Mohamed

Comment: Mod. please I don't understand why you blocked my question, this a q/a type of site and no the documentations. please take your ill manners else where